# How fibonacci function expand?

Tags: haskell

I have a very simple fibonacci function:

```
fibs = 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs
```

But I can't figure out how it's going to expand. As you can see, it's a recursive function.

The fibonacci sequence numbers are(start by one):

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, n
```

The second number (the number 1) on sequence above, for me it is not clear, why is `1` not `2`.

Please explain me, how `fibs` is going to be expanded?

**Update**

I tried expand as follow:

```
fibs = 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs

scanl (+) 1 [1](fibs) = 1 : (
                                case [1] of
                                    [] -> []
                                    x:xs -> scanl (+) (1+1) [1](fibs)
                            )

scanl (+) 2 [1](fibs) = 2 : (
                                case [1] of
                                    [] -> []
                                    x:xs -> scanl (+) (2+1) [1](fibs)
                            )

scanl (+) 3 [1](fibs) = 3 : (
                                case [1] of
                                    [] -> []
                                    x:xs -> scanl (+) (3+1) [1](fibs)
                            )
```

As you can see, the tail is always return `[1](fibs)`, that is of course wrong.
The last expression should be:

```
scanl (+) 3 [2](fibs) = 3 : (
                                case [2] of
                                    [] -> []
                                    x:xs -> scanl (+) (3+2) [3](fibs)
                            )
```

But I could not image, how does it works.

Comment: When I read `Haskell Programming from first principles`  there was the same expression and it took me a few chapters more until i finally understood how it worked.

Comment: Yes I am reading the book.

Comment: By the way, it is not a recursive function, since it's not a function at all. You can call it a recursive list, or (perhaps more clearly) a list defined recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will be more clearer:

```
-- scanl f z [x1, x2, ...] == [z, z `f` x1, (z `f` x1) `f` x2, ...]
let fibs = 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs

   fibs
=> 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs
=> 1 : scanl (+) 1 (1:...)
=> 1 : 1 : scanl (+) (1 + 1) (tail $ 1:1:...)
=> 1 : 1 : scanl (+) 2 (1:...)
=> 1 : 1 : 2 : scanl (+) (2 + 1) (tail $ 1:2:...)
=> 1 : 1 : 2 : scanl (+) 3 (2:...)
=> 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : scanl (+) (3 + 2) (tail $ 2:3:...)
=> 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : scanl (+) 5 (3:...)
=> 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : 5 : scanl (+) (5 + 3) (tail $ 3:5:...)
=> 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : 5 : scanl (+) 8 (5:...)
=> 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : 5 : 8 : scanl (+) (8 + 5) (tail $ 5:8:...)
=> 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : 5 : 8 : scanl (+) 13 (8:...)
=> 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : 5 : 8 : 13 : scanl (+) (13 + 8) (tail $ 8:13:...)
=> 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : 5 : 8 : 13 : scanl (+) 21 (13:...)
=> 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : 5 : 8 : 13 : 21 : scanl (+) (21 + 13) (tail $ 13:21:...)
=> 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : 5 : 8 : 13 : 21 : scanl (+) 34 (21:...)
```

Answer (score 3):

We have

```
fibs = 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs
```

and can lookup the definition of `scanl` to be

```
scanl                   :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
scanl                   = scanlGo
  where
    scanlGo           :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
    scanlGo f q ls    = q : (case ls of
                               []   -> []
                               x:xs -> scanlGo f (f q x) xs)
```

For the following analysis, we will simply think of `scanlGo` as `scanl`.

We want to see, how haskell evaluates the expression

```
  let fibs = 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs
```

Full disclosure: As the expression is written, it doesn't get
evaluated at all (ignoring possible implementation details).

Why is that? Haskell is lazy and expression are evaluated until
they reach "Weak head normal form", which means, that an expression
is evaluated until we get an resulting expression, which is normal
form or which is a data constructor or an lambda awaiting an argument
(i.e. a partially applied function).

So the value bound to the name fibs is already in weak head normal
form, as it is an data constructor with arguments.

```
 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs
-- ^ this is the data constructor
```

So to get haskell evaluate anything at all here, we need to prod it
a little.

Let's start with

```
  tail fibs
```

you can't type that in ghci, as it will try to print it, which will
further try to evaluate it ad inifinitum. So if you want to experiment
with ghci, use

```
let t = tail fibs
head t
```

So how would the expression `tail fibs` be evaluated? It goes roughly
like this:

```
    tail fibs
  = tail (1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs)
  = scanl (+) 1 fibs
  = 1 : case fibs of { [] -> []; x:xs -> scanl (+) (1 + x) xs ; }
  --  ^ data constructor
```

and here it stops, as we reached a data constructor. `head $ tail fibs` is
now easily evaluatable, without the need to evaluate the case expression any
further. This result will hopefully also be memoized, so haskell now knows,
that the expression known as `fibs` can be evaluated to

```
1 : 1 : case fibs of { [] -> []; x:xs -> scanl (+) (1 + x) xs ; }
```

Lets ask for `tail (tail fibs)`:

```
  tail (tail fibs)
= tail (1 : case fibs of { [] -> []; x : xs -> scanl (+) (1 + x) xs; }
= case fibs of { []-> []; x : xs -> scanl (+) (1 + x) xs; }
= scanl (+) (1 + 1) (tail fibs)
= 2 : case (tail fibs) of { [] -> [] ; x:xs -> scanl (+) (2 + x) xs; }
--  ^ data constructor
```

and here it stops again. Again the result will be memoized and haskell now
knows, that the expression fibs, can be evaluated to:

```
1 : 1 : 2 : case (tail fibs) of { [] -> []; x:xs -> scanl (+) (2+x) xs; }
```

and now it goes on like that, if you ask for further elements, remember haskell
won't evaluate the expression further, after reaching normal form or a data
constructor or a partially applied function, if you don't ask for it.

**old answer:**

So basically it is

```
fibs = 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs
fibs = 1 : 1 : scanl (+) 2 (tail fibs)
fibs = 1 : 1 : 2 : scanl (+) 3 (tail (tail fibs))
fibs = 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : scanl (+) 5 (tail (tail (tail fibs)))
fibs = 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : 5 : scanl (+) 8 (tail (tail (tail (tail fibs))))
```

In the evaluation of the next list element, `scanl` get evaluated. So we directly get the next element as the value handed to scanl as second parameter. For the then following element haskell stores the computation, which will always evaluate the second branch of the case, as we are always one element *behind* in consuming fibs. Here the next fibonacci number is calculated as `f q x`.

Of course it will not be some stacked succession of `tail` calls in the
last parameter of `scanl`, but there will be some method of keeping the position in the list in a more direct way, as we already computed it. I used those stacked `tail` calls to enable an easier understanding.

PS: Additional answer to one the comments:

```
1: tail fibs = scanl (+) 1 fibs
2:           = scanl (+) 1 (1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs)
3:           = 1 : scanl (+) 2 (scanl (+) 1 fibs)
-- with the equation from line 1 we can do
4:           = 1 : scanl (+) 2 (tail fibs)

5: tail (tail fibs) = scanl (+) 2 (tail fibs)
6:                  = scanl (+) 2 (1 : scanl (+) 2 (tail fibs))
7:                  = 2 : scanl (+) 3 (scanl (+) 2 (tail fibs))
-- with the equation from line 5 we can do
8:                  = 2 : scanl (+) 3 (tail (tail fibs))
```

and so on.

PSS: In your try to expand it, you set `fibs = [1]` which is wrong. It is
`1 : some computation, not yet done` thanks to lazyness.

Comment: `tail fibs = 1 : scanl (+) 2 (tail fibs)`

Comment: what is `tail fibs`?

Comment: It is so difficult to understand, I need a bit time to understand it. But thanks so much for your help.

Comment: One more question about `(tail fibs)`. Consider following expression `fibs = 1 : 1 : 2 : scanl (+) 3 (tail (tail fibs))`, how it gets the value `2`? The `scan` function calls fibs at tail and how does it get the last value from the const cell?

Answer (score 1):

Scan and fold are similar except in one thing. In fold the result being the final value but in scan, it's a list of all the intermediate values up to the final one.
As we're concatenating first number onto the front of the list, the first fibonacci number will be 1. The second fibonacci number will also be 1 (the second argument to scan), after that every fibonacci number  is the sum of the previous number (scan's running total) and the one before that.

Answer (score 0):

A perspective that helped me realize what is happening in this
sequence is to remove the recursion and construct it by hand. To
illustrate this better, I will use a Fibonacci sequence starting with
2 and 3:

```
[2, 3, 5, 8, ...]
```

Here all the terms are different, so it is easier to distinguish
between them.

First, no recursion is needed to produce the first two members:

```
λ> 2 : (scanl (+) 3 [])
[2,3]
```

That is, the first member is given and the second member `3` is the
value given as initial accumulator for `scanl`.

So when recursion kicks in, the sequence is `[2, 3]`. At this point
the value of the accumulator is 3 and the first term of the sequence
is the next value consumed by `scanl`.

```
λ> 2 : (scanl (+) 3 [2])
[2,3,5]
```

Thus the next output is `3 + 2 = 5` as expected.

After this the value of the accumulator is 5 and the next value
consumed by `scanl` is 3, so the next output is 8.

```
λ> 2 : (scanl (+) 3 [2, 3])
[2,3,5,8]
```

Hope this helps (someone).